# Magento Solr search returns nothing on queries with norwegian characters

Tags: magento, solr, special-characters

I've setup Solr search on my Magento installation, but it doesn't return any results when searching for a word containing norwegian characters, e.g. "læring" (learning), and I have many products with "læring" in the title.

I'm unable to figure this out and would appreciate any help.

schema.xml is [located here](http://pastebin.com/zr5gMj9N).

Many thanks.

Comment: Are your norwegian texts go into fields with _nb ending? Also, which version of Solr are you using? Version 4 has a good admin console to troubleshoot this kinds of issues, but your schema.xml seem to indicate an older version of Solr.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by _nb ending?

Comment: Your schema says that your Norwegian type analysis is for: **<fieldType name="text_nb"**, which maps to dynamic fields with ending in _nb: **<dynamicField name="*_nb" type="text_nb"**. So, if your content is not ending up in the field ending in _nb, they do not get parsed as **text_nb** and - as far I can tell - are not parsed according to your Norwegian rules.

Answer (score 1):

For characters out of the ASCII-charset you have to update your Tomcat connector:

```
<Server ...>
 <Service ...>
   <Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
     ...
   </Connector>
 </Service>
</Server>
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#line-90